# Should I delete things created by the new keyword in main.cpp?

Tags: c++, memory

If I understand correctly (which I am not claiming I do), you should `delete` anything created with the `new` keyword in your `Destructor` for a particular class.  That prevents memory leaks.  Example:

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar *bar_ = NULL;

Foo::Foo()
{
    bar_= new Bar;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete bar_;
    bar_ = NULL;
}
```

But should you `delete` `new` things created in `main.cpp`?  Or will they just be automatically deleted by their `Destructors` when they go out of scope?

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
    MakeNewFoo();
    //Do other stuff and forget foo ever existed
    exit(0);
}

void MakeNewFoo(){        
    Foo *foo = new Foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *" Or will they just be automatically deleted by their Destructors when they go out of scope?"*

No, they wouldn't be deleted, you'll get memory leaks.

In general you don't use `new`/`delete` directly in C++. You rather use a smart pointer from the standard [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) classes:

```
class Foo {
    unique_ptr<Bar> bar_;

public:
    Foo() : bar_(new Bar) {}
    ~Foo() {} // delete is automatically managed by unique_ptr<Bar>
};
```

Same for your free function sample:

```
void MakeNewFoo(){        
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
    // Do stuff with foo
} // Will be deleted as soon foo goes out of scope
```

---

But if you use `new`/`new[]` you always have to cleanup using `delete`/`delete[]`, yes.

Comment: If you are using C++14, you can use `make_unique()` instead of `new` directly: `bar_(make_unique<Bar>())`

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes, clean up your memory.

Longer answer:

I don't know of an OS that *won't* clean up memory leaks created by you, but you should do it anyway. It becomes especially helpful when you are running a memory leak detection tool, and aren't deluged by a bunch of "false" positives from main.cpp.

Besides, what about something like this?

```
int main()
{
   BigStructure foo* = new BigStructure(/*...*/);
   // some computations to get variables
   // at this point foo is no longer needed
   RestOfProgramFunction1(); // long running, resource heavy
   RestOfProgramFunction2(); // long running, resource heavy
}
```

Now you've held onto a bunch of memory you don't need anymore, which leaves less memory available for the other functions you'll need.

You are responsible for freeing up *any* memory you allocate. If you don't want to care about *when* to do it, use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, which will free up the memory for you when they go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks!  I never said cuz I never really thought about it, but I meant new keywords outside of the `main()` method.  Does this change the answer at all?

Comment: Doesn't change the answer. You are always responsible for freeing that memory. If you don't want to worry about *where* you should be freeing it, use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 2):

Everything you create with `new` will exist during the whole execution of your program in memory, or when it is removed using `delete`. So yes, you should delete `Foo` before exiting `MakeNewFoo`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you showed will not compile, because `new` returns a pointer, but your `foo` and `bar_` variables are not declared as pointers, so you need to fix that:

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar *bar_ = NULL;

Foo::Foo()
{
    bar_= new Bar;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete bar_;
    bar_ = NULL;
}
```

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
    MakeNewFoo();
    //Do other stuff and forget foo ever existed
    exit(0);
}

void MakeNewFoo(){        
    Foo *foo = new Foo;
}
```

Now, with that said, you can see that `MakeNewFoo()` has a memory leak, since the `Foo` object being allocated with `new` is never freed using `delete`.  Yes, technically the OS will reclaim the memory when the process terminates.  But what if `MakeNewFoo()` were called in other places of your code besides `main()`?  So it is good practice to always `delete` whatever you `new` (or let C++ do it for you, via the `std::auto_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::shared_ptr` smart wrapper classes).